# How can MLE Likelihood evaluations be so different if I break up a log likelihood into its sum?

Tags: matlab, statistics

This is something I noticed in Matlab when trying to do MLE. My first estimator used the log likelihood of a pdf and broke the product up as a sum. For example, a log weibull pdf `(f(x)=b ax^(a-1)exp(-bx^a))` broken up is:

`log_likelihood=log(b)+log(a)+(a-1)log(x)-bx^a`

Evaluating this is wildly different to this:

`log_likelihood=log(bax^(a-1)exp(-bx^a))`

What is the computer doing differently in the two stages? The first one gives a much larger number (by a couple orders of magnitude).

Comment: The answers below are likely correct, but it's not possible to tell because you haven't supplied us with code that can actually be run to reproduce the problem. For some problems it's hard to give a short reproducible example, but it should be trivial in this case.

Comment: diplodo, please accept one of the answers if they answered your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work on a scientific software project implementing maximum likelihood of phylogenetic trees, and consistently run into issues regarding numerical precision. Often the descepency is ...

1. between competing applications with the same values in the model,
2. when calculating the MLE scores by hand,
3. in the order of the operations in the computation.

It really all comes down to number three, and even in your case. Mulitplication of small and very large numbers can cause weird results when their exponents are scaled during computation. There is a lot about this in the (in)famous "[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)". But, what I've mentioned is the short of it if that's all you are interested in.

Over all, the issue you are seeing are strictly numerical issues in the representation of floating point / double precision numbers and operations when computing the function. I'm not too familiar with MATLAB, but they may have an arbitrary-precision type that would give you better results.

Aside from that, keep them symbolic as long as possible and if you have any intuition about the variables size (as in `a` is always very large compared to `x`), then make sure you are choosing the order of parenthesis wisely.

The first equation should be better since it is dealing with adding `log`s, and should be much more stable then the second --although `x^a` makes me a bit weary as it would dominate the equation, but it would in practice anyways.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the numbers you use, this could be a numerical issue: If you combine very large numbers with very small numbers, you can get inaccuracies due to limitations in number precision.

One possibility is that you lose some accuracy in the second case since you are operating at different scales.

Comment: This sounds like what is going on.